# TSQL using a @parameter as the SQL column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question number parameter '@QNumber varchar(5)' (Value: Q8, Q9 and Q10)
Q8, Q9 and Q10 is the actual SQL column name, and when I use the @Parameter to dynamically pass the value Q8, Q9 and Q10 the count is always same even though they are not.

```
declare @qnumber varchar(5) = 'Q8' 
select total = count(*) 
from table1 
where @qnumber is not null
```

Comment: Your having issues because some of your *data* (the question number) has instead been embedded in your *metadata* (here, a column name). If you redesign your tables so that each question occupies its *own* row and the question numbers are actually present in a column, as *data*, the query is trivial to write.

Comment: You **cannot** parametrize a table or column name in a regular T-SQL query. If you must do this, there's no alternative to using **dynamic SQL** with all its warts and shortcomings ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server will not accept a table name or a column name as a parameter. If you tried to do it with sp_executesql.

All about dynamic parameters read on https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing the column name as a parameter, you cannot use it as normal variable. Format the query dynamically and execute it.

```
declare @qnumber varchar(5) 
declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(1000)
set @qnumber='Q8' 
select total=count(*) from table1 where @qnumber is not null
set @sqlQuery = N'SELECT total=count(*) from table1 where ' + @qnumber + ' is not null'
exec (@sqlQuery)
```

Comment: [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) would be needed here to guard against SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
DECLARE @qnumber varchar(5) = 'Q8' 
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(500) = 
'select total = count(*)  from table1  where' + @qnumber +' is not null'
EXEC ( @sqlQuery )
```